# Attribute Error when loading CustomDataset into HuggingFace Trainer

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch

I'm following this webpage, trying to load a pandas dataframe into a pytorch dataset in order to use the Trainer API:https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training#train-with-pytorch-trainer. My script is shown below.

```
modelName='bert-base-uncased'
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(modelName)
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(modelName, num_labels=6)

def tokenizeFunction(sentence):
    return tokenizer(sentence, padding="max_length", truncation=True)

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe, tokenizer):
        self.data = dataframe
        self.tokenizer=tokenizer
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        text = self.data.loc[idx, "text"]  # 'text' column
        emotions = self.data.loc[idx, "emotions"]  # 'emotions' column
        inputs = self.tokenizer(
            text,
            padding="max_length",
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors="pt"
        )

        return {
            'input_ids': inputs["input_ids"].squeeze(),
            'attention_mask': inputs["attention_mask"].squeeze(),
            'labels': int(emotions),
        }

#Tokenizing the training and text strings
trainDataset=CustomDataset(trainDF, tokenizer)
testDataset=CustomDataset(testDF, tokenizer)
trainLoader=DataLoader(trainDataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
testLoader=DataLoader(testDataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)

trainingArgs= TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./results",
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    save_steps=500,
    eval_steps=500,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=trainingArgs,
    train_dataset=trainLoader,
    data_collator=lambda data: {"input_ids": data[0], "attention_mask": data[1], "labels": data[2]},
    eval_dataset=testLoader,
)

trainer.train()
```

With this code I keep getting an attributeError, "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'size'". How would I go about fixing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fix your code, dataset is not pandas dataset, it's pyarrow table and they have different column name, there is no  loc method, and you need datasets as parameters in Trainer and it's staring to train model

```
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("yelp_review_full")

modelName='bert-base-uncased'
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(modelName)
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(modelName, num_labels=6)

trainDF = dataset["train"]

testDF = dataset["test"]

def tokenizeFunction(sentence):
    return tokenizer(sentence, padding="max_length", truncation=True)

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe, tokenizer):
        self.data = dataframe
        self.tokenizer=tokenizer
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):

        text = self.data["text"][idx]
        emotions = self.data["label"][idx]
        inputs = self.tokenizer(
            text,
            padding="max_length",
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors="pt"
        )

        return {
            'input_ids': inputs["input_ids"].squeeze(),
            'attention_mask': inputs["attention_mask"].squeeze(),
            'labels': int(emotions),
        }

#Tokenizing the training and text strings
trainDataset=CustomDataset(trainDF, tokenizer)
testDataset=CustomDataset(testDF, tokenizer)
trainLoader=DataLoader(trainDataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
testLoader=DataLoader(testDataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)

trainingArgs= TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./results",
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    save_steps=500,
    eval_steps=500,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=trainingArgs,
    train_dataset=trainDataset,
    # data_collator=lambda data: {"input_ids": data[0], "attention_mask": data[1], "labels": data[2]},
    eval_dataset=testDataset,
)

trainer.train()
```